# Open a website on button click in j2me?

Tags: button, java-me, web, launcher

Hi I am trying to open a website in emulator as click on button.Please give me suggestion how can I do it? I want to open website in emulator not in browser. Please help me.

Comment: I dont, think its possible in J2ME

Answer (score 1):

Midlet.platformRequest() is probably what you are looking for.See [this article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/invoking-applications/invoking-applications-in-java-me.html) for more details.

Comment: No this is not working. I have also tried by creating object of midlet class then using obj.platformRequest(url) but it does not giving me any result.And I can open website in browser through button click in emulator .But I want to open that website in emulator window.I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Some simulators do not open the default browser. Install other simulators. Simulator from Samsung opens the S.O. native browser (from PC), but not inside in emulator. I'm not sure, but I believe the Nokia simulator simulates the browser open. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Series_40/

Comment: It's worth noting that `platformRequest()` returns a boolean which indicates whether the midlet must exit before the request can be fulfilled. As well as checking its return value, the method may also throw a `ConnectionNotFoundException`, which should also be handled. For more info, see http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Make a MIDlet Object and implement following code.

`private MIDlet m;`

`String url = "http://www.google.com";`

`MyMidlet.m = this;`

`m.platformRequest(url);`

this code is worked in my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LWUIT then try the [HTMLComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjidhgf.html)

Comment: I can not use  HttpRequestHandler in j2me in lwuit It does not support this class. Can u say what is the problem? Or i need to include any jar file for using it?

Comment: The page I mention in my answer says "This example does not implement a DocumentRequestHandler. It uses the HttpRequestHandler (a ready-made implementation that can be found in the LWUITBrowser application) instead. LWUITBrowser be checked out from the LWUIT SVN under MIDP/applications."